# First and last pivot element vs generic placement with very large N

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I've implemented a QuickSort algorithm along with a Time-Complexity control. It works fine with smaller N but once i get closer to larger N the StackOverflow is inevitable. Im thinking that having the pivot element as the last element might be what's causing this.

My first thought was to simply always use the middle element as the pivot element to avoid this but since the test-program throws an 'unsorted exception', it's not a valid solution.

Any ideas how i can work my way around this?

```
public class QuickSorter implements IntSorter{

int partition (int a[], int lo, int hi) {
    int pivot = a[hi]; // pivot element
    int i = (lo - 1);

    for (int j = lo; j <= hi - 1; j++) {
        if (a[j] < pivot) {
            i++;
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
        }
    }
    int temp = a[i+1];
    a[i+1] = a[hi];
    a[hi] = temp;
    return (i + 1);
}



@Override
public void sort(int[] a) {

    int lo = 0;
    int hi = a.length-1;
    if (lo < hi) {
        int p = partition(a, lo, hi);
        sort(a, lo, p - 1);
        sort(a, p + 1, hi);
    }
}

private void sort(int[] a, int lo, int hi) {
    if (lo < hi) {
        int p = partition(a, lo, hi);
        sort(a, lo, p - 1);
        sort(a, p + 1, hi);
    }
}
}
```

Testcode:

```
private static void testSort(IntSorter sorter, int firstN, boolean ordered) {
    double t1 = 0;
    int N = firstN/2;

    while (t1 < 0.7 && N < 10000000) {
        N *= 2;
        int[] a = create(N, ordered);
        t1 = timeit(sorter, a);
        System.out.println("T("+N+")="+t1);
        ArrayUtil.testOrdered(a);
    }
    int[] a = create(4*N, ordered);
    double t4 = timeit(sorter, a);
    ArrayUtil.testOrdered(a);
    double t01 = t1 / (N   * Math.log(N  )); 
    double t04 = t4 / (4*N * Math.log(4*N));
    System.out.println("T("+4*N+")="+t4+" growth per N log N: "+t04/t01);
    if (t04/t01 > 1.25) {
        System.out.println(sorter.getClass().getName()+".sort appears not to run in O(N log N) time");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

public static void testOrdered(int[] a) {
    int N = a.length;
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        if (a[i] < a[i-1]) {
            throw new SortingException("Not sorted, a["+(i-1)+"] > a["+i+"]");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Quicksort should work with any pivot albeit runtime characteristics might change (e.g. chosing the last element might lead to a lot of recursions if the array is already pretty much sorted). If your algorithm doesn't sort properly if you choose the middle element then it's wrong and you'd need to check that (step through the code with a debugger).

Comment: Btw, instead of `j <= hi - 1`  you could use `j < hi`.

Comment: @Thomas I see! But am i correct in the sense that the thing that would cause stackoverflow error is in fact the amount of recursions happening when using the last element?

Comment: This would have to be analyzed but it is likely. Think about what would happen if you'd try to sort an array like [1,2,3,4,5] and take the last element as the pivot. You'd end up with empty "greater" arrays and "smaller" arrays like [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3], [1,2], [1], i.e. you'd do one recursive call for each element in the worst case. This of course could still happen when selecting the middle element if this always happens to be the largest (e.g. if the array was [ 2,4,5,3,1] (which would result in "lower" arrays [2,4,3,1], [2,3,1], [2,1], [1]) but it is less likely. to be "sorted" that way.

Comment: In any case recursion can suffer from stackoverflow no matter which element you choose as the pivot, you just can reduce the likelyhood of this happening (an already sorted or almost sorted array is much more likely than a "freak" order). If you want to remove that risk altogether you should think about replacing recursion with iteration (this might help you get the idea: https://www.techiedelight.com/iterative-implementation-of-quicksort/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Thomas comments, using the middle element as the pivot should work fine. It's a common choice, actually, because it works well with input arrays that happen to be already fully or partially sorted.

As for avoiding stack overflow, a common approach is to only recurse on the shorter part after a partitioning step - this ensures at least a halving of the array being processed at each level, so e.g. a 1,000,000 element array will have a maximum call depth of roughly 20 ( log2(1,000,000) ).

So, instead of

```
private void sort(int[] a, int lo, int hi) {
    if (lo < hi) {
        int p = partition(a, lo, hi);
        sort(a, lo, p - 1);
        sort(a, p + 1, hi);
    }
}
```

You do

```
private void sort(int[] a, int lo, int hi) {
    while (lo < hi) {
        int p = partition(a, lo, hi);
        // recurse on smaller part, loop on larger part
        if (((p - 1) - lo) > (hi - (p + 1))) {
          sort(a, p + 1, hi);
          hi = p - 1;
        }
        else {
          sort(a, lo, p - 1);
          lo = p + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep that works very well, thank you! I also tried to shuffle the array before sorting and that seems to work aswell. :)

Answer (score 0):

Shuffle the array before sorting with the method below seems to have fixed the issues i had aswell

```
public void shuffle(int[] a) {
    int N = a.length;
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int r = i + randomGenerator.nextInt(N-i);     // between i and N-1
        int t = a[i]; a[i] = a[r]; a[r] = t;
    }
}
```